# How to use autograd.gradcheck in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

The documentation does not include any example use case of gradcheck, where would it be useful?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's an example use case provided in the documentation here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/extending.html

> You probably want to check if the backward method you implemented
>   actually computes the derivatives of your function. It is possible by
>   comparing with numerical approximations using small finite
>   differences:
>
> ```py
> from torch.autograd import gradcheck
>
> # gradcheck takes a tuple of tensors as input, check if your gradient
> # evaluated with these tensors are close enough to numerical
> # approximations and returns True if they all verify this condition.
> input = (torch.randn(20,20,dtype=torch.double,requires_grad=True), torch.randn(30,20,dtype=torch.double,requires_grad=True))
> test = gradcheck(linear, input, eps=1e-6, atol=1e-4)
> print(test)
> ```

As the quote above suggests, the purpose of the `gradcheck` function is to verify that a custom backward function agrees with a numerical approximation of the gradient. The primary use case is when you're implementing a custom backward operation. **In very few cases should you be implementing your own backward function in PyTorch**. This is because PyTorch's autograd functionality takes care of computing gradients for the vast majority of operations.

The most obvious exceptions are

1. You have a function which can't be expressed as a finite combination of other differentiable functions (for example, if you needed the incomplete gamma function, you might want to write your own forward and backward which used numpy and/or lookup tables).
2. You're looking to speed up the computation of a particularly complicated expression for which the gradient could be drastically simplified after applying the chain rule.

Comment: What does the first argument in the gradcheck function refer to? A linear layer? How do I use it with a custom function that I've written?

Comment: The documentation for `gradcheck` can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.autograd.gradcheck). The first argument is a function which takes a tensor (of same size and type as `input`) and returns a tensor or tuple of tensors.